# Google Cloud Storage not strongly consistent, returning 404 until 500ms after a resumable upload completes

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, google-cloud-storage, consistency

I am making a file uploader using Cloud Storage which is experiencing non-consistent behaviour which seems contrary to the documentation.

> When you upload an object to Cloud Storage, and you receive a success response, the object is immediately available for download and metadata operations from any location where Google offers service. This is true whether you create a new object or replace an existing object. Because uploads are strongly consistent, you will never receive a 404 Not Found response or stale data for a read-after-write or read-after-metadata-update operation. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/consistency#strongly_consistent_operations

... but I receive a 404 if I read it immediately after upload.

The process is as follows:

1. my backend NodeJS API initiates a resumable upload creating a Session URI to a bucket
2. then the user uploads the file directly to GCS via a PUT to the Session URI from the browser
3. the front-end posts an update to my API to say the upload is complete.
4. my API then tries to download the same file as a stream and ingest it

I got it all working, but then found that when a new file is uploaded (i.e. doesn't already exist in the bucket), there is a 500ms delay required between the upload finishing (step 2) and the read succeeding (step 4). If I do it without the delay I get a 404.

[The docs states](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/consistency) that generally uploads are available immediately, unless there's some caching in place.

> Important: Cached objects that are publicly readable might not exhibit strong consistency. [See Cache control and consistency](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/consistency#cache-control) for details.

I'm using the `XMLHttpRequest` to upload the file to GCS and using the `load` event to detect the completed upload. [From what I read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) this should mean the 200 response has been received, and therefore the file is in place. Although debugging the load event shows it's just another "progress" event at 100%.

**What I've tried**

The workaround is to add a `setTimeout(done, 500)` to the final callback in the load event handler, before calling my API at step 3.

I've tested this dozens of times and it's reliable, repeatable where 0 - 400ms fails and about 500ms+ "fixes" it always.

I've tried adding the [cache control headers to the original POST as recommended](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/consistency#cache-control), which sets up the upload session to have no caching - adding `no-store` which seemed the right one. This I can see reflected in the headers of the PUT (it actually puts more no-cache options in the response than I set). This didn't seem to affect the behaviour at all.

If the file is already there in the bucked and gets overwritten, this doesn't happen. (Although I guess there might still be race condition in the contents if I uploaded a different file).

I can't seem to catch the exception so I don't really know which call to GCS is returning the 404, whether it's  `bucket.file()` or `remoteFile.createReadStream()` or later reading from it (which is deep in some other library that I'm passing the readable stream into).

I haven't tried a try/retry loop because I can't even catch the error. That's what I'd like to do if I can't get *consistent* behaviour guaranteed.

I have tried using [the gcs-resumable-upload package](https://github.com/googleapis/gcs-resumable-upload#readme) and the direct use of [Storage.File](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#createResumableUpload), both seem to work the same.

**The Code**

The NodeJS API which starts the upload is like this:

1a) `gcs-resumable-upload` version

```
const {createURI} = require('gcs-resumable-upload');

        const sessionURI = await createURI({
            bucket: bucketName,
            file: filename,
            origin: origin,
            customRequestOptions: {                     //todo: this doesn't fixe the race
                headers: {
                    'Cache-Control': 'no-store',
                },
            },
        });
```

1b) `Storage.File` version

```
const {Storage, File} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();
        const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);
        const file = bucket.file(filename);
        const resp = await file.createResumableUpload({origin: origin})
        const sessionURI = resp[0];
```

2. The upload step looks like this, (JS in the browser) which opens the file and uploads it:

```
            var reader = new FileReader();
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.upload.addEventListener("load", function(e){
                setTimeout(done, 500);// todo I get 404s in the next step without 500ms delay?
                // done();  // fails
            }, false);

            xhr.open("PUT", sessionUrl);
            xhr.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined-binary');
            reader.onload = function(evt) {
                xhr.send(evt.target.result);
            };
            reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
```

4. The backend NodeJS API basically does this (with some error handling):

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();

        const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);
        let remoteFile, stream;
        remoteFile = bucket.file(filename);
        stream = remoteFile.createReadStream()
```

`stream` is then returned and sent off to a library which uses it to read the contents.

This is where it errors, although it's erroring async in a tick event, and I haven't managed to try/catch it from anywhere yet (which is a bit odd).

**The error**

The error stack is:

```
 <ref *2> ApiError: No such object: MY-BUCKETNAME/MY-FILENAME
    at new ApiError (node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:59:15)
    at Util.parseHttpRespMessage (node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:161:41)
    at Util.handleResp (node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:135:76)
    at Duplexify.<anonymous> (node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/file.js:880:31)
    at Duplexify.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Duplexify.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:548:15)
    at PassThrough.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at PassThrough.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:548:15)
    at onResponse (node_modules/retry-request/index.js:208:19)
    at PassThrough.<anonymous> (node_modules/retry-request/index.js:155:11)
    at PassThrough.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at PassThrough.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:548:15)
    at node_modules/teeny-request/build/src/index.js:184:27
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

and the error message is a big structure:

```
{
  code: 404,
  errors: [],
  response: <ref *1> PassThrough {
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
      length: 0,
      pipes: [],
      flowing: false,
      ended: true,
      endEmitted: true,
      reading: false,
      sync: false,
      needReadable: false,
      emittedReadable: false,
      readableListening: false,
      resumeScheduled: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: true,
      destroyed: true,
      errored: null,
      closed: true,
      closeEmitted: true,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      awaitDrainWriters: Set(0) {},
      multiAwaitDrain: true,
      readingMore: false,
      decoder: null,
      encoding: null,
      [Symbol(kPaused)]: true
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      prefinish: [Function: prefinish],
      error: [Array],
      close: [Array],
      end: [Function: onend],
      finish: [Function: onfinish]
    },
    _eventsCount: 5,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: true,
      ended: true,
      finished: true,
      destroyed: true,
      decodeStrings: true,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: false,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      buffered: [],
      bufferedIndex: 0,
      allBuffers: true,
      allNoop: true,
      pendingcb: 0,
      prefinished: true,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: true,
      errored: null,
      closed: true
    },
    allowHalfOpen: true,
    statusCode: 404,
    statusMessage: 'Not Found',
    request: {
      agent: false,
      headers: [Object],
      href: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/MY-BUCKETNAME/o/MY-FILENAME?alt=media'
    },
    body: [Circular *1],
    headers: {
      'alt-svc': 'h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"',
      'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0',
      connection: 'close',
      'content-length': '55',
      'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
      date: 'Tue, 23 Mar 2021 08:08:50 GMT',
      expires: 'Tue, 23 Mar 2021 08:08:50 GMT',
      server: 'UploadServer',
      vary: 'Origin, X-Origin',
      'x-guploader-uploadid': 'ABg5-Uz0P1kWSLFABXOpJ_mbQY5-4wEnMekQduBli1S4aYDWoIgqVKG1M5zlZ_ePd0iJDlzCl_ThYvmFpvcXpgwCcnN993kZog'
    },
    toJSON: [Function: toJSON],
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kTransformState)]: {
      afterTransform: [Function: bound afterTransform],
      needTransform: false,
      transforming: false,
      writecb: null,
      writechunk: null,
      writeencoding: 'buffer'
    }
  },
  domainEmitter: PassThrough {
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
      length: 0,
      pipes: [],
      flowing: true,
      ended: false,
      endEmitted: false,
      reading: true,
      sync: false,
      needReadable: true,
      emittedReadable: false,
      readableListening: false,
      resumeScheduled: false,
      errorEmitted: true,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: true,
      destroyed: true,
      errored: [Circular *2],
      closed: true,
      closeEmitted: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      awaitDrainWriters: null,
      multiAwaitDrain: false,
      readingMore: false,
      decoder: null,
      encoding: null,
      [Symbol(kPaused)]: false
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      prefinish: [Function: prefinish],
      reading: [Function: makeRequest],
      data: [Function (anonymous)],
      end: [Function (anonymous)]
    },
    _eventsCount: 4,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: false,
      ended: false,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: true,
      decodeStrings: true,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: true,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      buffered: [],
      bufferedIndex: 0,
      allBuffers: true,
      allNoop: true,
      pendingcb: 0,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: true,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: true,
      errored: [Circular *2],
      closed: true
    },
    allowHalfOpen: true,
    _read: [Function: bound ],
    _write: [Function (anonymous)],
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kTransformState)]: {
      afterTransform: [Function: bound afterTransform],
      needTransform: true,
      transforming: false,
      writecb: null,
      writechunk: null,
      writeencoding: null
    }
  },
  domainThrown: false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have since discovered that the error happens when the first stream *read* occurs, which in my case was deep in a third-party library which attached on('data') events to the stream I passed it. So `bucket.file(path)` works, `file.createReadStream()` works and doesn't error, but as soon as you read from the stream it emits the "file not found error".

So I wrote a pre-test workaround where I open the stream myself, before passing it to the 3rd party library, read it a bit for one 'data' event, and then close it, and create and pass on a second stream. If it fails during this pre-reading, I catch the error, and wait recursively using a timer. This works and I found it catches and fixes errors about 30% of the time, sometimes waiting for about 2s.

I then discovered that the utility method `file.exists()` reports the same boolean as my test-read loop, so I could simplify the pre-test workaround to use that as the flag to wait.

```
    async waitTillFileExists(filename, file){
        let retries = 20;
        let delay = 500; //ms

        // Recursive setTimeout, with a promise wrapper that the caller can await.
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
            const fnTest = async () => {
                const fileExistsResponse = await file.exists()
                if(fileExistsResponse[0]){
                    return resolve(true);
                }
                else if(retries-- > 0){
                    setTimeout(fnTest, delay);
                }
                else reject(`waitTillFileExists ${retries} retries exhausted!`);
            }
            // begin
            setTimeout(fnTest,delay);
        });
    }
```

This isn't a solution to the original consistency problem but effectively solves it, by assuming the file save and subsequent fetch is not going to be immediately consistent.

Comment: Have you kept using this solution since then? How does it work with large files?

Comment: Yes I have kept using it, and I've seen in the logs it is usually waiting for one or two loops. I've not analysed the behaviour versus files size though. Might be interesting - if I get time to do that I will update the answer.

Comment: I've stumbled upon the same issue when uploading from a signed URL. I also ended up implementing a solution with retries but I'm not sure if it is future proof. I created this issue that will hopefully clarify what's going on: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/issues/1801

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Cloud CDN or any third-party CDN?

Asking for two reasons:

> Cloud Storage is also compatible with third-party CDNs

[source](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/caching)

> For the best performance when delivering content to users, we
> recommend using Cloud Storage with Cloud CDN.

[source](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/caching#performance_considerations)

I would suggest first to look if you already have any CDNs in place that might be affecting object caching and therefore cause the delay you mentioned.

If that is not the case, I suggest using Cloud CDN as the docs state that combined with Cloud Storage it gives the best performance. Besides the optimized performance it might bring, Cloud CDN also has some [caching settings](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/caching#preventing-caching) you might find interesting.

Finally, you mentioned the use of the `no-store` flag in the HTTP request, but note the following:

> Note: Cache-Control is also a header you can specify in your HTTP
> requests for an object; however, Cloud Storage ignores this header and
> sets response Cache-Control headers based on the stored metadata
> values.

[source](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#cache-control)

Comment: No I'm not using a CDN of any kind.

Comment: The no-store flag was set in the header of the (my) POST which creates the object and sets the stored metadata. The note above is about the subsequent (user) GETs which ignore the client's cache request and uses the metadata set by the original POST.

Comment: I saw the `no-store` flag but it might be ignored as stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#cache-control) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/consistency#cache-control). That's why I suggested using the CDN's cache settings rather than GCS', but I realised there are other steps before that like forcing the GCS settings to apply the `no-store` flag (although I didn't find how to force it) or uploading the file, and the [modifying the metadata](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#editable) to ensure it's set to no-store.

Comment: Also, check the object is publicly available and is not stored in a bucket that has requester pays enabled. Otherwise Cache-Control will [not apply](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#caching_data).

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue and solved it by waiting for the last `readystatechange` event to determine the upload had ended instead of the `load` or `loadend` events.

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = (event) => {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
        // upload is really completed
    }
};
```

Comment: Aha! Now I read more on the events, I see it's more complex than I thought. I didn't look at the total/loaded properties, maybe it's not finished yet. I will give it a go when I get time to return to that project.

Comment: @scipilot Has this solved the problem for you, too?